# Writing access to a realtime database lost, after switching page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little problem when writing to a DB, using firebase user authentication.

In a given page, say myPage.html; I need to access a realtime database to perform some data writing. I have code to check that I am properly logged in:

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      ... some useful code ...
      // OK to perform DB writes.
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      ... Get-Out-Of-Here ...
      // NG to perform DB writes.
    }
  });
```

Up to this point all is OK, I can write to the DB as expected, if I am logged in.

Then I need to perform some more writings, from another page (myOtherPage.html).

There is a link in myPage.html going to myOtherPage.html.

```
<a href='myOtherPage.html'>Go To The Other Page</a>
```

Here comes the problem:

From myOtherPage.html, I can no longer perform any data writing to the DB.

It looks like my authentication is just gone away.

What should I do to keep access to the DB even if I change page?

Comment: What are you doing on `myOtherPage.html` to restore the user's authentication state?

Comment: At this point, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the issue if you aren't using `Authentication State Persistence` about which you can read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

Some code snippet from the official documention:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function() {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

And here's type of states available:

[image: states availabe]

Using the 'LOCAL' state should be fine with your need and your user needs to log out himself which mean he'll stay logged in and can access your database unless he logs out.

PS: *The default for web browser and React Native apps is local (provided the browser supports this storage mechanism, eg. 3rd party cookies/data are enabled) whereas it is none for Node.js backend apps.*

Comment: On most environments the authentication state should be automatically persisted. Why do you think this is the problem here?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I had a similar issue a few weeks ago and adding the persistence state to local solved my issue. Though I later removed the authentication completely from that site for some reasons. I was getting logged out on refresh.

Comment: Though I'll try to recreate same project with two pages again and check it

Comment: I tried. For the time being it is working with Safari but not with Firefox (non-private window). 
I get a message in the console: "uncaught exception: Error: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type."
Anyway, you pointed the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Michel must be anything related FireFox. Maybe version issue or so. I'll try in firefox once and let you know .

Comment: Great job in helping @Dharmaraj. As far as I can tell though, this should not be needed. If you can reproduce it, could you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with details?